# How to hide params passed in url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a peculiar situation, my website is like

```
www.example.com/page.php?url=homepage
```

. I am trying to use .htaccess file to make url look like

```
www.example.com/page/homepage/
```

There by hiding the ".php?url=" part in the url. is this possible? please suggest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /anything/anything -> anything.php?url=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_])/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?url=$2 [L]

</IfModule>
```

If the `page.php` filename will always be the same, then do it like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# /page/anything -> page.php?url=anything
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: I want to view the URL like http://www.example.com/blog/new-post instead of  http://www.example.com/blog/blog-page.php?blog=new-post using htaccess. Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/$ /page.php?url=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This code you can hide you page name

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$  pagename.php?name=$1&id=$2    [NC,L]
```