# How can I hide my URL parameter using .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So this is my htaccess file as Wordpress supplies it

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have a page at /events, that I want to add a block of text via a template PHP file, depending on if a URL parameter exists.

So I took a look online, and tried to write an .htaccess rule for it. What I came up with was this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^events/([^/\.]+)/?$ events/?flow=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

However, I don't think this is working how I'd like it to. The link from the original page is /events?flow=open-evenings and in the events page, I have the usual $_GET thing:

```
$flow = isset($_GET['flow']) ? $_GET['flow'] : '';
if($flow == 'open-evenings') { echo "blah"; }
```

But when I try to view the URL /events/open-evenings I get the 404 error page. Have I placed the rule in the wrong place, or am I not doing something obvious? All help is appreciated!

**Update**: this is using Wordpress, so maybe i shouldn't be using the already rewritten urls? Should I be using index.php instead? But will that still pickup the pretty urls that I'm trying to use?

I've tried to change the URL to index.php, to try and get that to work, but with the below rule, I'm still getting a 404 page.

```
RewriteRule ^events/([^/]*)$ /index.php?flow=$1
```

Can anyone help me try to get this working?

Comment: The `[L]` flag prevents further rules from picking up the rewritten target.

Comment: But the fact it's showing page not found, means the rule I've written isn't working correctly, and it's first in the list. The same behaviour happens with and without `[L]`

Comment: No the 404 means that there's no directory/file that matches `./events`. So presumably that's a virtual request path, or not?

Comment: It's a page in Wordpress, so I suppose it is virtual, yes?

Comment: If it's not a real php entrance script, then it's virtual. The catch-all must pick it up.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by php entrance script..

Comment: @mario I have updated my question, it may help you

Answer (score 3):

This will do the following:

```
1>   temp.example.com/save.php?item=xxxxx&id=xxx&type=1 
2>   temp.example.com/save.php?item=xxxxx&id=xxx&type=2
```

to be like

```
1>   temp.example.com/save/xxxxx/xxx
2>   temp.example.com/save/xxxxx/xxx
```

You can use these rules in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /save\.php\?item=([^\s&]+)&id=([^\s&]+)&type=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ save/%1/%2/%3? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^save/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ save.php?item=$1&id=$2&type=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Let me know if that helps...

Replace the needed values to yours. Is this something similar that you need?

Comment: Well that's very complicated, I'm not an expert at making htaccess rules, so it would be helpful if you could use my examples as a base, and help explaining which parts do what?

Comment: Please refer to the edited answer. And let me know.. If that is something that you are looking for.

Comment: Inserted after `ReWrite Base /` as `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /events\.php\?flow=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ events/%1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^events/([\w-]+)/?$ events?flow=$1 [L,QSA,NC]` but it doesn't appear to have changed anything.

Comment: did you put it in the root .htaccess file?

Comment: Please refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897819/how-to-hide-params-passed-in-url-using-htaccess

Comment: I have read that question, and used the accepted answer to try to add something more to my question, but it didn't work. I have updated my question, it might help you, to help me!