# Remove GET parameters in link?

Tags: php

I have an API link like :

> www.mydomain.com/api.php?key=test&action=say&what=hi

And I would like to access it like :

> www.mydomain.com/api.php/test/say/hi

Is it possible ? I didn't found.

Comment: yes it is possible through `.htaccess`.

Comment: It's what I expected, but how, please ?

Comment: search for .htaccess rewrite url

Comment: If it's a third-party Api you are accessing then you can't do that. If this is your local API then only `.htaccess` re-write rule will work

Comment: Update here what you have done(or approach) to achieve this

Comment: It's a local API, but I don't find how to do what I want ..

Comment: I've done nothing because I don't know how to rewrite correctly urls with htaccess

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897997/4248328

Comment: `.htaccess` is one of the worst ways to configure your server, as the config has to be parsed for every relevant request.  It's also not a good idea to blindly recommend this without even knowing what web server is in use!  The only relevant key word here is "URL rewriting".  @MattBelcaustier There's tons of questions on this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Its an API url right? than you didn't get it on browser hit. Are you getting this in php according to your question tages

Comment: Ok so, I tried all of your links answers guys and I can't achieve it with more than 1 parameter, can anybody write a complete solution, if possible, please ?

Comment: Yes @AjeetKumar it's an API but it can be browser side too, if we can say this like that. I simply want to remove ?xx= / &xxx= from it, like said in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting API url modification using php then you can use this below function

```
<?php
//Suppose we have URL in string format
//$apiLink = 'www.mydomain.com/api.php?key=test&action=say&what=hi';

//if we doesn't know, or it will be dynamic all times getting from browser
$apiLink = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$sendNewUrl = makeNewURL($apiLink);
header("location: ".$sendNewUrl);

function makeNewURL($apiLink){
    $totalParams = "";
    $apiData = explode("?",$apiLink);
    $apiParameters = explode("&",$apiData[1]);
    if(count($apiParameters)>0){
        foreach($apiParameters as $params){
            if(strpos($params, '=') !== false){
                $expected = explode("=",$params);
                $totalParams .= $expected[1];
                if($totalParams!=""){
                    $totalParams .= "/";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $apiData[0]."/".$totalParams;
}
```

Comment: @Matt Belcaustier can go through that way to get a changes in api URL and use/redirect it to where we need..

Comment: I don't understand why you want to make a new URL + I get an Error 500

Comment: So what approach you want to go.. clear the points. how you are getting values (API URL) and what you want to achieve by process. your question is not clear.

Comment: if you want re-write only url, its only possible when you have access to write htaccess code on that api server

Comment: I want to access to `api.php?key=test&action=say&what=hi` by `api.php/test/say/hi`

Comment: I mean : If I write `api.php/test/say/hi` in my browser, I want it to do like if I was writing `api.php?key=test&action=say&what=hi`