# Hide url parameters from the GET request

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide some url parameters from the `$_GET` request using `.htaccess`. I have tried different approaches and of course from this link: [How to hide params passed in url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897819/how-to-hide-params-passed-in-url-using-htaccess)

But it failed for me:

[Error image - hidden id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dViPt.png)

My `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /$1.php
```

But this works only when `id` is added:

[With ID works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFWVY.png)

I want to hide the `id` and display it like this:

`localhost/get_test.net/test/4`

**Update:**
So, it works with this code:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/\.]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Now I need to change `test.php` to any link and fix the issue with `index.php` page, because it is not found:

[Index page not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iS9P.png)

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file located?

Comment: @MrWhite

Hi! I use the `WAMP` for local testing: [Screenshot](https://i.ibb.co/n0kyjsS/2018-11-25-194904.png). Thanks.

Comment: From your screenshot, it looks like your `.htaccess` file is located in the `/get_test.net` subdirectory (the same directory that the `test.php` script is located). However, your directive rewrites the request back to `/test.php` in the document root - which would not seem to work, unless you have another `test.php` in the document root? You say "it works", however, the regex wouldn't match the URL `/test/4`?

Comment: @MrWhite 

I changed the code to: `RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+) test.php?id=$1 [NC,L]` but it still fails to get the value from `$_GET` request: [Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dViPt.png). 

I don't have any `test.php` in the document root: `C:\wamp64\www`. I only have it here: `C:\wamp64\www\get_test.net\`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file structure is like this (from your screenshot):

```
/get_test.net
    .htaccess
    test.php
    index.php
```

Then to rewrite `/get_test.net/<file>/<id>` to `/get_test.net/<file>.php?id=<id>`, where `<id>` is numeric and `/<id>` is optional then you would need to do something like:

```
# Prevent conflict with mod_negotiation
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

# Do NOT set RewriteBase (or set it to the subdirectory)
#RewriteBase /get_test.net

# Rewrite /<file>/<id> to <file>.php?id=<id>
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(?:/(\d+))?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

There is no need to escape the literal dot when used in a regex character class.

**UPDATE:** The above also handles the situation when the trailing `/<id>` is omitted from the URL. eg. `/index` is rewritten to `/index.php?id=` (not the empty URL param). Note also that if the trailing slash is provided then the ID must also consist of 1 or more digits.

Comment: All good, but `index` page was not found because I need to hide `.php` extension. 

Previously I used this code: 
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php`

But now it doesn't work: [Screen2](https://i.ibb.co/TYVrL9h/2018-11-25-202530.png)

Comment: Ah, so `/<id>` is optional?

Comment: Yes, for example:

`index` - main page
`test?id=XX` - navigation from index (main page)