# How to redirect users to their specific subfolders?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Ok, so I tried to Google it, make it by myself, but I just messed up my website, so after days of trying, I'm here to ask.

I want to redirect my users to their own subdirs. Examples:

- `www.example.com/username1` -> `www.example.com/userpages/username1`
- `www.example.com/username2` -> `www.example.com/userpages/username2`
  and so on.

Of course, `username` can be almost anything, but `www.example.com` and the subdir `userpages` are fixed.

How can I do this with `.htaccess`?

Comment: Why make a directory for every user? Create a page with a specific name and some GET parameters eg. `people.php?username=username1 ` and [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897819/how-to-hide-params-passed-in-url-using-htaccess) to hide the GET variables

Comment: Users will have more files and pages, so I would like to separate them from each other. In the root dir I don't want to have >100 subdirs for each users, that's why I want to put every userpage to a fixed subdir. And also they have to open their pages with a simple url, not with some php and get variables.

Comment: It would be interesting to see what you have tried since it is hard to see what the problem is - are there additional complexities that we are not aware of?

Comment: It sounds like what you possibly actually need is a content management system, not a load of static subfolders and files.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to describe is a relatively straight forward redirect. However, the URL structure you have chosen will naturally create conflicts. What about URLs like `/about` and `/contact` etc.? Or is *everything* a username?

To redirect `example.com/<username>` to `example.com/userpages/<username>` you could do the following using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /userpages/$1 [R,L]
```

Note that this assumes that every URL that contains a single path segment is a *username*.