# use .htaccess in hiding variables in address bar

Tags: php, .htaccess

Good day!
I am very new to htaccess and have no idea what is it all about.

I am trying to save data in to my database and I want to hide my variables in my address bar.

This is what I am using right now

localhost/foldername/save.php?update=1

And I want it to be like this

localhost/foldername/successfully-saved-data

Thank you so much for your help.

Can you please tell me on what should I do with my redirect page command in my insert into statement.

Thank you!!!

Comment: You can POST the values instead of using GET. Or use session variables. In my opinion they are far easier solutions that htaccess  rewrite

Comment: Are you able to simplify your code to present to us the PHP or HTML that you've written so far that works, but needs the redirection to tidy it up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to hide params passed in url using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897819/how-to-hide-params-passed-in-url-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # /anything/anything -> anything.php?url=anything
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_])/([^/]*)$ /$1.php?url=$2 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

If the `page.php` filename will always be the same, then do it like this:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    # /page/anything -> page.php?url=anything
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ /page.php?url=$1 [L]

    </IfModule>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6897997/9606095